# How to store Public Certiticate (.cer file) in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault

How can I upload or store public key (.cer) file in azure keyvault. From the keyvault panel it gives error when I tried to upload any .cer file where It works for .pfx file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider if Key Vault is the appropriate solution for your scenario. The public key (by nature) is not confidential data, you don't need a secure place to store it. You can use a general purpose storage service for it.

If you still need to use Key Vault, you can store it as a secret. Key Vault secrets are octet sequences with a maximum size of 25k bytes each.

Answer (score 7):

## Loading Public Key Certificates

[Azure Key Vault Explorer](https://github.com/elize1979/AzureKeyVaultExplorer) allows you to load public key certificates (.cer files).

Certificates are stored as keys in the Key Vault using a "standard" format used by that application (since .cer files aren't natively supported by Azure Key Vault).

[image: Example public key cert as stored by Azure Key Vault Explorer]

## Accessing Public Key Certificates

Once you have loaded public keys into the Azure Key Vault, they can then be accessed programatically as follows:

```cs
// load certificate based on format used by `Azure Key Vault Explorer`
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var certBundle = await kv.GetSecretAsync(secretIdentifier).ConfigureAwait(false);

byte[] certBytes = null;
if (certBundle.ContentType == "application/x-pkcs12")
{
    certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certBundle.Value);
}
else if (certBundle.ContentType == "application/pkix-cert")
{
    certBytes = certBundle?.Value.FromJson<PublicKeyCertificate>()?.Data;
}
if (certBytes != null && certBytes.Length > 0)
{
    return new X509Certificate2(certBytes,
        "",
        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
        X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
        X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
}
return null;

...

// class used to access public key certificate stored in Key Vault
public class PublicKeyCertificate
{
    public byte[] Data;
}
```

Comment: For those following these instructions.  Install Azure Vault using `https://aka.ms/ve?vault://[ENTER HERE YOUR VAULT NAME]`.  Then, in the Vault application, press Add > Key Vault Certificate > From File.   Select your .cer file and press OK.

Comment: i spent couple hours to connect to subscription or keyvaults - no luck...